# citation within caption

Tags: captions, citing

The following code produces an error:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{errormeasures}
    \caption[Ma{\ss}zahlen zur Evaluation der SVM-Regression]{Ma{\ss}zahlen zur Evaluation der SVM-Regression, wobei Kennzeichnung mittels $\ast$ auf die Verwendung des arithmetischen Mittels des Trainingsdatensatzes $\bar_{a}$ hinweist \protect\citep{hall2011data}.}
    \label{fig:errormeasures}
\end{figure}
```

The use of protect doesnt work. It produces the error:

"Missing } inserted. .420 ...$ text \protect\citep{hall2011data}.}
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)"

I'm using bibliographystyle dinat (DINAT.BST   Version 2.5   2000-11-14 
%% (c) Helge Baumann) and documentclass zihpub from my university.

Does anyone know how to use citation with citep in a caption of a figure?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what "doesnt work" means. E.g., are you getting error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Please also indicate which bibliography style and which document class you employ.

Comment: The error message you've just posted strongly suggests that the error is *not related* to either `\protect` or `\citep`. Please state what's on l.420 of the input file. Does the the caption really contain "textetxtetxt"? Do you have any math-y terms in the real caption or, possibly, a string that contains special characters such as `_` (underscores)?

Comment: The string `$\bar_{a}$` is the culprit. Did you mean to write `$\bar{a}$` -- *without* the underscore? At any rate, `$\bar_{a}$` is not syntactically correct, inside or outside a caption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is not -- as claimed in the posting -- about \protect or \cite but, instead, by a typo in an inline math expression.

Comment: Im sorry that I didn't see the error. Thanks very much for you help. I just didn't see it although I looked at the code a couple of times.

Comment: No need to apologize! TeX's error messages can be confusing and unilluminating to all but the most experienced TeXnicians.